# How to get just sent mail from Google Takeout archive of email?

Tags: gmail, export, google-takeout

User found out that Google Takeout mixes Inbox and Sent mail into one `.mbox` file.

So user exported only sent mail. However, the `.mbox` contains also replies to some sent mail.

How can user export *just* sent mail from gmail via Google Takeout?